# CakePHP how to route /error/404 to /errors/error404

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am trying to beautify my URLs a bit but I'm not sure how to set up a route so that:

`/error/403` goes to `/errors/error403`

`/error/404` goes to `/errors/error404`

`/error/500` goes to `/errors/error500`

etc.

At the moment I have this but I don't know where to go with it. How do I grab the action parameter and put it into the URL like I would with .htaccess?

```
Router::connect('/error/:action/*', array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => ??));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two way of doing this (it seems I always start my answers with this phrase).

First would be to write all the custom urls by hand

```
Router::connect('/error/404', array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'error404'));
Router::connect('/error/500', array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'error500'));
```

which seems rather ugly. But you can put that inside an array to pretty-fy it.

```
$errorTypes = array('403', '404', '500')
foreach ($errorTypes as $error)
    Router::connect('/error/'.$error, array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'error'.$error));
```

Or, you can do something more cake-ish (I think)

```
Router::connect('/error/:code', 
     array('controller' => 'errors',  'action' => 'generalError'),
     array('pass' => array('code'),
           'code' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Which implies that you need a new function in your ErrorsController that receives the code and send it to the different actions

```
class ErrorsController extends AppController {
    public function generalError($code) {
       if ($code == 404)
          $this->error404();
       else if ($code == 500)
          $this->error500();
       /*etc*/
    }
}
```

Both work, but it depends on your actions, if they handle more parameters, what do you find prettier...